# AWS Athena query data scanned and time taken

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I ran below 2 SQL queries in Aws Athena QUERY1 and QUERY2. I just selected everything in QUERY1, but in QUERY2 I did some transformations which is given in detail in QUERY2.

Table preprocessed comprises of three columns namely column1, column2 and id.
All these three columns are of string type.
SHOW CREATE TABLE preprocessed result:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `preprocessed`(
`column1` string COMMENT '',
`column2` string COMMENT '',
`id` string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUT FORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
's3://mybucket/myobject'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

Data scanned in QUERY1 = 13 MB
Time taken in QUERY1 = 12sec

Data scanned in QUERY2 = 27MB
Time taken in QUERY2 = 18 sec

Data scanned in QUERY2 is twice as much as in QUERY2. I think this is because I am scanning dataset twice in QUERY2 . I want my data scanned to be improved to approximately 13MB for QUERY2

```
QUERY1 :
WITH dataset AS
(
SELECT column1, column2, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS value FROM preprocessed
)
SELECT * FROM dataset

QUERY2 :
WITH dataset AS
(
SELECT column1, column2, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS value FROM preprocessed
),
dataset_1 AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM dataset
),
dataset_2 AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT column2 FROM dataset
),
dataset_3 AS
(
SELECT column1, column2 FROM dataset_1, dataset_2
)
SELECT * FROM dataset_3
```

Comment: This question is far from clear, posting the complete query, table structures, example data and expected results would help out alot here..

Comment: *"Data scanned in QUERY2 is twice as much as in QUERY2. I think this is because I am scanning dataset twice in QUERY2 . I want my data scanned to be improved to approximately 13MB for QUERY2"* I would suggest to run `EXPLAIN query` also and post the results here.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56833159/edit) the question with information, don't just comment it..

Comment: I have given the complete query and table structure also. However I don't know how to get query plan in Athena.

Comment: *"table structure also"*  i don't see it ? `SHOW CREATE TABLE preprocessed` we need to know datatypes and indexes as this is a performance question ? *"However I don't know how to get query plan in "*  `EXPLAIN query`  should work.

Comment: I have posted the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE preprocessed but in Athena explain query is not working as it works in MySQL.

Comment: iam going to remove the MySQL tag as this code isn't MySQL valid.. It does not help to leave this tagged with MySQL.. Mainly to avoid futher wrong suggestions..

Comment: Okay, sorry for that tag.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is currently not possible with Athena. If I understand your question correctly you would like to compute the cross join of the distinct values of `column1` and `column2`.

Athena doesn't reuse results from named queries, which means that in your query when `dataset_1` and `dataset_2` are evaluated they will both run the statement in `dataset`.

To avoid reading the source table twice you will have to compute the distinct values of `column1` and `column2` in one query. This can be done with the [`array_agg`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html#array_agg) function and [`UNNEST`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/sql/select.html#unnest):

```
SELECT
  column1,
  column2
FROM (
  SELECT
    array_agg(DISTINCT column1) AS column1_values,
    array_agg(DISTINCT column2) AS column2_values
  FROM preprocessed
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (column1_values) c1 (column1)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (column2_values) c2 (column2)
```

You'll have to test how well it performs for large cardinalities.

Comment: Yes, your query is giving the correct result. But it is doing the same scan as my query. I think is because it is scanning the required column only and no twice scanning is taking place. It first scanned column1 and then column2.

Comment: When you say "as my query" do you mean your first or second query? Which query is it doing the "same scan as"? Are you saying my suggestion is what you were after, or that it scans too much data?

Comment: Actually, It is recommended to switch to Redshift if complex queries start arising on large datasets, as it outperforms Athena.